# how can I make MySQL return a specific number of rows or less for all select queries without limit clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database containing 10,000 records and I want all select queries to return only 30 rows or less without mentioning the limit clause in the queries

**is this possible?**

Comment: In tools like `MySQL Workbench` you can set the limit to default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `SQL_SELECT_LIMIT` [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_select_limit)

It defines maximum number of rows, that will be returned from SELECT statements.

`SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = 1;`

If a SELECT has a LIMIT clause, the LIMIT takes precedence over the value of sql_select_limit.

This parameter can be set global or per session.